How to trigger the Omega Attack and Special in Hades 2?
I am confused how to use the Omega (Ω) Attacks and Special in the tutorial. I am at the very beginning, using the default weapon (The Witch's Staff).
It says:

Ω Attack: Hold for the Attack X
Ω Special: Hold Y then Release Y

Yet even though I seem to do that, it never activates.
Am I missing a specific condition? Or am I missing the specific timing? I cannot tell what I am doing wrong.


You need to get your magick energy back. Omega attack, special, and cast require this resource, i.e. 20, 10, 15 magick. You used up your magick, which is why they don't trigger.

